# mptopdf package required when using xcolor package

Tags: color, miktex

In my `MikTex TexWork` I'm getting the following warning with a 'package install dialog box' when I run the following tex document. The error does seem to be related to `xcolor` package because if I remove `\usepackage{xcolor}` from preamble document typesets fine. But I do need xcolor package for other scenarios. The example below was just a test scenario for the brevity of this post:

**Warning**: `the required file tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii is missing. It is a part of following package mptopdf`

**tex Document**:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

This \(t^{4}+6\) is a test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `xcolor` loads a driver file. In this case, `pdflatex` is very likely be used and the driver file `pdftex.def` is loaded. The driver file contains both the code for color and graphics. The driver file `pdftex.def` supports some kind of simplified PostScript, the output of MetaPost, as image file format. This was implemented in ConTeXt by Hans Hagen and `pdftex.def` loads these ConTeXt files: `supp-pdf.mkii` and some other files. If the ConTeXt files are missing, `pdftex.def` still continues to work, but throws an error message, if MetaPost PostScript files should be included as graphics.

If you want to get rid of the warning, then these ConTeXt files should be installed as suggested by the warning text.

Comment: In my case only colors are used from xcolor package for displaying certain typesets. Do I still need to install `mptopdf` package. I couldn't find `ConTeXt` in `MikTeX's` Package Manager.

Comment: @nam Install `mptopdf` if you want to get rid of the warning.